# How to change the color of selected row in gwt-ext grid?

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I am want to change the color of selected row of grid (gwt-ext grid) in my application.

For this I have done this:

```
int rowIndex = getGrid().getStore().indexOf(rec);
Element currentRow = getGrid().getView().getRow(rowIndex);
currentRow.getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor","red");
```

But it is permanently changing the color of the row.As I select on another row it previous selected row should be in it previous color.

So I am not getting what to do the change the color of selected row in the gwt-ext grid.

I also want to know how to change the text color of the grid row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think the right was is to add (or modify the existing) css class for the row and not to make this in your java code. The class can you add with `addStyleName("myClass")`.
2. Alternative (but wrong for me) - you can reset the color for all rows before you set the color for the selected row.

Comment: i have tried for 2 option but it is not working properly.About one first i need to create a css class which can set the color of row.If have an css for it or related then plz share it.Thanks for reply